# How do I change the fetch and push actions targets for deploying heroku apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, github

Right now when I type git remote -v in the terminal when I am in my applications directory I get:

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:falling-samurai-3043.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:falling-samurai-3043.git (push)

origin  git@github.com:obsideous/sample_app.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:obsideous/sample_app.git (push)
```

`falling-smurai-3043` no longer exists because I destroyed it from my account on the heroku website. I would like it to look like:

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:(one that I create).git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:(one that I create).git (push)

origin  git@github.com:BigBoy1337/sample_app.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:BigBoy1337/sample_app.git (push)
```

`obsideous` is my old account and `BigBoy1337` is my new GitHub account that I am trying to switch everything over to.
How can I accomplish these changes. I am a noob at this stuff so the more detailed the better. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the remote name by typing ([`git remote` man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-remote.html)):

```
git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:(one that I create).git
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:BigBoy1337/sample_app.git
```

That will update both `push` and `fetch` addresses in your git `config` file.